# How to trigger Google Apps Script 'On Form Submit' for Contact Form 7 forms?

Tags: php, forms, google-apps-script, contact-form-7

I want log contact form (I'm using Contact Form 7 on my site) submissions to a Google sheet. My approach so far has been to:

1. Write Google Apps Script (script) to handle form submissions and deploy as WebApp
2. Set Google Apps Script trigger to fire "On form submit"
3. Set custom form action on Contact Form 7 form (replace it with Web App thingy)
4. ...
5. Success?

This works when I test it out offline (locally), but fails on my website - after successful form submission (I get the "Form submitted successfully" message from Contact Form 7) nothing seems to happen, the script doesn't seem to trigger at all, and I can't figure out why.

My main suspicion is AJAX form submission that Contact Form 7 uses by default, but I'm not sure.

Please find the code below.

Google Apps Script to handle and log form submissions to

```
function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    sheet.appendRow([e.parameter.text-name, e.parameter.company-website, e.parameter.text-email, e.parameter.text-message])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success'}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }
  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Contact Form 7 hook to replace form action:

```
function custom_action_url( $url ) {
    $wpcf7    = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $wpcf7_id = $wpcf7->id();

    if ( $wpcf7_id == 17582 ) {
        $url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/deployedWebApp/exec';
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_action_url', 'custom_action_url' );
```

In the end I get my Contact Form 7 form with the updated action:

```
<form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/deployedWebApp/exe" method="post" class="wpcf7-form init" novalidate="novalidate" data-status="init">
    <div class="my-form">
    <label class="label-form">Your Name<font>*</font></label><br>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="text-name"><input type="text" name="text-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required"></span><br>
    <br><br>
    <label class="label-form">Company Website</label><br>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="company-website"><input type="text" name="company-website" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required"><div data-lastpass-icon-root="true"></div></span><br>
    <br><br>
    <label class="label-form">Your email<font>*</font></label><br>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="text-email"><input type="email" name="text-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email"></span><br>
    <br><br>
    <label class="label-form">Message<font>*</font></label><br>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="text-message"><textarea name="text-message" cols="40" rows="4" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required"></textarea></span><br>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control has-spinner wpcf7-submit button-submit"><span class="wpcf7-spinner"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is my approach good here? Any way to debug why the trigger is not working online?

My other idea was to use Contact Form 7 post submit hook and make a curl request using php, but I would still like to figure out why the above is not working.

Comment: Try ``onChange`` trigger

Comment: @TheMaster Same result, works in local, but does not work when I put it on the live site.

Comment: Browser Logs and server side logs? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  How to ask and provide webapp info

Comment: How is authorization being handled. I would think you would have to set up a service account if you are accessing from an external website.